# Get json response from webpage to c++

Tags: php, c++, json

so I am trying to get a json response from my api and then return true or false based on the response but I just cant wrap my head around it. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
The query I send to the page is: https://redacted.com/api.php?login=test123&password=test123&hwid=12345 - you can look at it yourself if you want.

And then what I receive is:
    {
    "error": true,
    "message": "Invalid username or password",
    "data": null,
    "status_code": -1
    }

I want to make a bool function that returns false if it gets that otherwise just return true.

My current code which I dont think handles json properly:

```
net::requests m_request(L"redacted-auth", false);
std::wstring answer = m_request.Post(false, URL, "login=%s&password=%s&    hwid=%s", username.c_str(), password.c_str(), (sw::sha512::calculate(hwid)).c_str());
if (answer == L"Try Again") {
    answer = m_request.Post(false, URL, "login=%s&password=%s&hwid=%s", username.c_str(), password.c_str(), (sw::sha512::calculate(hwid)).c_str());
}   

return answer != L"You have successfully login" ? false : true;
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more details such as (1) the code you have so far for getting the JSON response from your API, (2) the expected JSON response, (3) the _specific_ problem you're facing (what _exactly_ can't you "_wrap your head around_" in)? Please read the [ask] page to describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: I added info sorry I am new to this website.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are storing json response in plain string. Have you tried any json-parsing librarys? [Rapid-json](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson) is looking good.

From it's [documentation](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html), it seems like you can do something like this:

```
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
using namespace rapidjson;
// Your code to get answer here
GenericDocument<UTF16<> > document;
document.Parse(answer);
std::wstring msg(document["message"].GetString());
return msg == L"You have successfully login";
```

I assumed you are using UTF-16 encoding. I have not tried the code, so it is possible that things do not go well. If so, comment me.

PS) You can be MORE specific, like providing the library you are using (What is `net::requests`?), what encoding you are using, or a self-contained example that we can reproduce.

**EDIT** Above code does not work. Following example works fine.

```
#include "include/rapidjson/document.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace rapidjson;

int main(void)
{
    std::wstring answer = L" { \"error\": true, \"message\": \"Invalid username or password\", \"data\": null, \"status_code\": -1 }";

    GenericDocument<UTF16<> > document;
    const wchar_t *newanswer = answer.c_str();
    document.Parse(newanswer);  
    std::wstring msg(document[L"message"].GetString());
    std::wcout << msg << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I forgot to add `L` prefix to `"message"`. Also, Rapid-json does not supports std::basic_string into their `Parse` method. The documentation is kind of messy...

Comment: I have tried your code and gotten this far:
`const wchar_t *newanswer = answer.c_str();
GenericDocument<UTF16<> > document;
document.Parse(newanswer);
std::wstring msg(document["message"].GetString());
return msg == L"You have successfully login" ? true : false;`

But it says https://gyazo.com/1332edac1cc969d2fd09371591d2824f
Ty for your help btw.

Comment: Hey, so there is one problem with that I need to retrieve the data from my URL....

Comment: @Flink And what is that problem? If it is a seperate problem, consider posting another question.

Comment: no I mean in your latest code you showed you didnt retreive the data from my url..

Comment: @Flink Oh, sure. But `answer` in my code is supposed to have same content as if you retrieve data from your server, so you can just copy and paste the four line: `GenericDocument<UTF16<> > document; const wchar_t *newanswer = answer.c_str(); document.Parse(newanswer); std::wstring msg(document[L"message"].GetString())` to your code.

Comment: @Flink Alternatively, You can just substitute `document["message"]` with `document[L"message"]` in the code at your first comment.